# como pasar un objeto js o php a uno json

Tags: javascript, php, json

Deseo cambiar un array de objetos ya sea de js a json o de php a json

En js estoy armando el js de la siguiente manera

```
self.form.attributesFields.contacts.contacts.forEach((item, i) => {
    contact.push({nombre: item.nombre.value, telefono: item.telefono.value, id_idioma: item.id_idioma.id});
  });
```

y obtengo como resultado:

```
[{nombre:"nombre",telefono:"(2323) - 232 3",id_idioma:1},{nombre:"nombre2",telefono:"(2424) - 242 4242",id_idioma:1}]
```

Como podria pasarlo a:

```
[{"nombre":"nombre","telefono":"(2323) - 232 3","id_idioma":1},{"nombre":"nombre2","telefono":"(2424) - 242 4242","id_idioma":1}]
```

Ya sea en php o js

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir un array con objetos a JSON puedes utilizar el método JSON.stringify()

```js
const arreglo = [{nombre:"nombre",telefono:"(2323) - 232 3",id_idioma:1},{nombre:"nombre2",telefono:"(2424) - 242 4242",id_idioma:1}];

const arrJson = JSON.stringify(arreglo);

console.log(arrJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir un array/objeto en PHP puedes usar json_encode: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php
    $arr = array(array("nombre" => "nombre", "telefono" => "(2323) - 232 3", "id_idioma" => 1), array("nombre" => "nombre1", "telefono" => "(2424) - 242 4242", "id_idioma" => 1));

    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

En JS puedes convertir un array/objetos a JSON con el método JSON.stringify()
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```
const arr = [{nombre:"nombre",telefono:"(2323) - 232 3",id_idioma:1},{nombre:"nombre2",telefono:"(2424) - 242 4242",id_idioma:1}]
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```